# Store image file in dynamically created folder

Tags: php, image, file, upload, directory

I want to store the image file with its path in a variable and then store this file in the folder created by me using `mkdir()`.

Here is my folder creation code:

```
<?php
$dirPath = "../leothian/jomres/uploadedimages/new_images2";
$result = mkdir($dirPath, 0777);
if ($result == 1)
{
    $dirPath = "../leothian/jomres/uploadedimages/new_images2/property";
    $result1=mkdir($dirPath,0777);
    if($result1=1)
    {
    $dirPath = "../leothian/jomres/uploadedimages/new_images2/property/0";
    $result2=mkdir($dirPath,0777);
    if($result2)
    {
        $dirPath = "../leothian/jomres/uploadedimages/new_images2/property/0/medium";
        $result3=mkdir($dirPath,0777);
    }
    $dirPath = "../leothian/jomres/uploadedimages/new_images2/slideshow";
    $result4=mkdir($dirPath,0777);
        if($result4=1)
        {

        $dirPath = "../leothian/jomres/uploadedimages/new_images2/slideshow/0";
        $result5=mkdir($dirPath,0777);


        }
    }
echo "Folders Created Sucessfully";
} 
else 
{
    echo "Error Creating Folders";
}
?>
```

Comment: help you how? you didn't tell us what the problem is, although... you do have a few issues I noticed

Comment: The issue is ..i want to store images in these dynamically created folders that i have mentioned in my code above...

Comment: Like...considering the folder "../leothian/jomres/uploadedimages/new_images2/slideshow" i want to add image files to this folder...i dont want to use form for selecting images

Comment: Just a side note: you have couple of invalid if checks that will not work as you have intended ($result1=1 for example). Additionally you should probably consider using the recursive parameter of mkdir to simplify your code...

Comment: the above code is working fine.... i just need a solution for iamges